# how to Compare the second part of the text in java?

Tags: java, string, compare, string-comparison

It is necessary to compare the second half of the text to see if they are brothers or not

I tried to find a solution to this problem

This is the problem link

https://codeforces.com/group/MWSDmqGsZm/contest/219158/problem/L

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s1 = in.next();
    String s2 = in.next();
    String s3 = in.next();
    String s4 = in.next();

    if (s3.length() == s4.length()) {
        System.out.println("ARE Brothers");
    } else {
        System.out.println("NOT");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the inputs, split by a space and get the second item in the resulting array to get the last name. Then compare the two using a ternary operator.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String firstLastName = s.nextLine().split(" ")[1];
String secondLastName = s.nextLine().split(" ")[1];
String result = firstLastName.equals(secondLastName) ? "ARE Brothers" : "NOT";
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

It says on the page that its providing two strings per line as { "first name" + "last name" }. You're reading in s1, s2 as first name + last name and then trying to compare s3 and s4 which is the second persons first and last name.

After that you need to change how you are checking if they're brothers. Checking the length of the string won't work, if I had a guy named Rex Davis and a person name Michael Smith your code would say that they're brothers even though they aren't.

Comment: you are right
What about this , if (s3== s4)
What's wrong , How is this resolved ؟

Comment: Use the .equals() function that is included in the java String class. If you compare a string class using "==" you're seeing if the location in memory is the same in the heap for both of the objects. Using s1.equals(s2) will check if the actual strings match or not.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would be another variation ?

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s1 = in.nextLine();
    String s2 = in.nextLine();

    String [] nameArr1 = s1.split(" ");
    String [] nameArr2 = s2.split(" ");

    String surname1 = nameArr1[1];
    String surname2 = nameArr2[1];

    if (surname1.equals(surname2)) {
        System.out.println("ARE Brothers");
    } else {
        System.out.println("NOT");
    }
}
```